# calculate Standard Error of mean of (means over distinct distributions)?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, clustered-standard-errors

As a motivating example, I want to pick the best racecar. The best racecar is the one that has the highest mean speed across 3 different racetracks (each racetrack is weighted equally).

If I take racecar A for some test drives and measure the following speeds:

```
racetrack 1: 88, 90, 92
racetrack 2: 67, 73
racetrack 3: 109, 110, 110, 111
```

the per-racetrack means and standard errors are

```
racetrack 1:  90 +/- 0.94
racetrack 2:  70 +/- 2.12
racetrack 3: 110 +/- 0.35
```

Note that I'm clearly drawing from three distinct distributions here.

the across-racetracks mean is `90`. What is my standard error, and how do I calculate it?

My intuition is that it should be less than the max of the per-racetrack standard errors (i.e. less than `2.12`).

For clarity: what I do *not* want to do is concatenate all my measured times into a single list:

```
all measurements: 67, 73, 88, 90, 92, 109, 110, 110, 111
```

and take the standard error of that, which yields `3.89`. The fact that `111` is much higher than `67` is not due to noise in measurements, it's due to the fact that racetrack 3 is easier/faster than racetrack 2.

Edit: I'm fine with a solution that assumes that each underlying distribution is something nice like a gaussian (in this example, one centered at `90`, one at `70`, one at `110`).

Comment: Welcome to CV! I think part of your problem is that your samples are very small. You could use the bootstrap to calculate the standard error of the mean, but with so little data I can't see how that is really feasible

Comment: What makes you think the the standard error would be less than the per-racetrack values?  There is a big difference between racetracks, so I would expect an overall standard error to account for differences between racetracks and so it would be greater.

Comment: How do you define 'best racecar'? Is it the car that has the highest average speed on the different tracks or the car that would win the most? (Those two might be different)

Comment: @abstrusiosity I found your answer not wrong in it's setup. It depends on whether the $\mu_i$ are considered a random effect (e.g. a random sample out of many possible racetracks which are assumed to follow some distribution in speeds) or a fixed effect. Your idea seems to be what the OP wants (or at least at some point he explicitly states that the differences in racetrack speeds are not to be considered random noise).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus in your words, I consider the difference between racetracks deterministic, a "fixed effect". E.g. racetrack 2 has lots of curves and therefore speeds are lower there. And for "best racecar", I mean specifically highest average speed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas how you might proceed. Maybe others on this site have
better ideas:

**Data.** Suppose sample 1 has $n_1 = 4, \bar X_1 = 10.78, S_1 = 0.77$
and sample 2 has $n_2 = 6, \bar X_2 = 15.07, S_2 = 0.41.$

```
set.seed(115)
x1 = rnorm(4, 10, 2);  mean(x1);  sd(x1)
[1] 10.78053
[1] 0.7696925
x2 = rnorm(6, 15, 1);  mean(x2);  sd(x2)
[1] 15.07297
[1] 0.4074099

stripchart(list(x1,x2), ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch="|")
```

[image]

**For equal variances.** Then use
$$\bar X_c = \frac{n_1\bar X_1 + n_2\bar X_2}{n_1+n_2} =
\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}\bar X_1 + \frac{n_2}{n_1+n2}\bar X_2,$$
a sample-size weighted average of the two sample means.

and, if you assume the two populations have the same variance, use

$$S_c^2 =  \frac{(n_1-1)S_1^2 + (n_2 - 1)S_2^2}{n_1 + n_2 - 2}
= \frac{\nu_1}{\nu_1+\nu_2}S_1^2 + \frac{\nu_2}{\nu_1+\nu_2}S_1^2,$$
where degrees of freedom $\nu_i = n_i - 1,$ a DF-weighted average of the two
sample variances. Use $S_c = \sqrt{S_c^2}.$

```
a.c = (4/10)*10.78 + (6/10)*15.07;  a.c
[1] 13.354
s.c = sqrt((3/8)*0.77^2 + (5/8)*0.41^2);  s.c
[1] 0.5721888
```

Finally, then a 95% CI for $\mu_c = (\mu_1 + \mu_2)/2$ uses the standard error
$\mathrm{SE}_c = S_c\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}$ and probability factor
$t^*,$ which cuts probability 0.025 from the upper tail of $\mathsf{T}(\nu_1+\nu_2) \equiv \mathsf{T}(n_1+n_2 - 2),$ so that the CI is $\bar X_c\pm t^*\mathrm{SE}_c.$
Notice that the standard error is the same as in a pooled two-sample t test.

```
CI = a.c + qt(c(.025,.975), 8)*s.c*sqrt(1/4 + 1/6);  CI
[1] 12.50229 14.20571
```

**Possibly unequal variances.** If you do not assume population variances to be equal, then you can use
standard error $\sqrt{{\frac{S_1^2}{n_1}}+\frac{S_2^2}{n_2}}.$ And the degrees of freedom for $t^*$ is $\nu^\prime,$ the same as for a Welch two-sample t test,
where $\min(n_1-1, n_2-1) \le \nu^\prime \le n_1+n_2-2.$

```
CI = a.c + qt(c(.025, .975), 4) * sqrt(.77^2/4 + .41^2/6);  CI
[1] 12.18842 14.51958
```

**More than two samples:** For the case where population variances are equal, generalization to more than two samples is straightforward. Otherwise, the degrees of freedom could use the same
Satterthwaite correction as in the one-factor ANOVA for possibly-unequal variances implemented in the R procedure `oneway.test`. If sample sizes
are moderately large, one might settle for $\nu^\prime \approx \min(n_i - 1).$

**Bootstrap CI:** @Stochastic has suggested a bootstrap, which may have a chance of being
useful for two somewhat larger sample---as for my fake data above.
A simple quantile nonparametric bootstrap in R, shown below gives the
95% CI $(11.97, 14.66).$

```
set.seed(2020)
a.re = replicate(10^6, mean(sample(c(x1,x2), 10, rep=T)))
CI = quantile(a.re, c(.025,.975))
CI
    2.5%    97.5% 
11.97321 14.65932 
summary(a.re)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  10.24   12.90   13.38   13.36   13.84   15.53 
hdr = "Bootstrap Dist'n of Weighted Means"
hist(a.re, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 abline(v=CI, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you propose a sample size based weighted average?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus:  I guess because $n_1\bar X_1 + n_2\bar X_2$ amounts to the sum of all my observations. Puzzled over this entire answer for a while because I'm not entirely sure I understand OP's goal. (If track 2 is as "important" as track 4, why only half as many runs there?) Would be interested in seeing alternative suggestions, as hinted in my first sentence.

Comment: ah, I see now. That would make sense when we assume $\mu_1 = \mu_2$.

Comment: With such differences from track to track, I'm not sure there is a 'typical' speed for this car.

Comment: @BruceET as a motivating reason, perhaps it's much harder/more expensive to collect samples on track 2 (e.g. it's in a far-away city, while track 4 is nearby). Also, I'm not looking for a sample-size weighted average. I'm interested in how good of an estimate $\bar X_1 + \bar X_2$ is for $μ1 + μ2$